# Why didn't MIB agents take the alien away from Harold's house?

Tags: men-in-black-international

In [Men in Black: International (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_Black:_International), Aliens broke into Harold's house. Two men in black, looking 
like agents, approached them. The agents suddenly flashed a 
Neuralyzer on them:

> MAN: A raccoon. Yeah, that's your problem, folks. Go ahead and make
>   sure those trash can lids are on nice and tight, and we were never
>   here.

They didn't even try searching the place. Why didn't MIB agents take the alien away from Harold's house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the MiB anticipated that the Tarantian would have gone into the house. It was seen hiding in the yard and the only other inhabitant of the house was asleep.

The official novelisation mentions that the they scanned the yard, then left at K(?)'s instruction, presumably to loop around to the other side of the house to see if they could pick up the proverbial scent.

> “He’s cute now,” the man in the black suit continued while his partner
>   silently scanned the yard, “but when these things hit puberty, they
>   turn into real monsters.”

Note that the Tarantian is capable of moving at at least 50mph over urban terrain, so stopping to investigate every single sighting is definitely going to result in them losing him.